Pairは同じ値しか持てないと課すことはできますか？
Data.Type.Equality の定義の意味がわかりません
について考えようとしています。
そこで、ふと思ったのですが、たとえばPairというよく知られてた構造（直積型）があります。
data Pair a b = Pair a b

examplePair :: Pair Int String
examplePair = Pair 10 "A"

10と"A"を保持できました（IntとStringを保持できました）。
これを同じ型のみしか保存できないようにするには簡単で下記のようにすればよいです。
data Pair a = Pair a a

examplePair :: Pair Int
examplePair = Pair 10 "A"

エラーになります。
hoge.hs:4:23: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Int
        Actual: String
    • In the second argument of ‘Pair’, namely ‘"A"’
      In the expression: Pair 10 "A"
      In an equation for ‘examplePair’: examplePair = Pair 10 "A"
  |
4 | examplePair = Pair 10 "A"
  |                       ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.

そして、下記のようにすればエラーになりません。（これで同じ型のみが保存できることが確認できました）。
data Pair a = Pair a a

examplePair :: Pair Int
examplePair = Pair 10 20

ここで質問です。Haskellの元々の構文や拡張機能で両方とも同じ値しか保持できないようにすることは可能でしょうか？
たとえば下記はOKですが、
examplePair = Pair 10 10

たとえば下記はNGにする方法です。
examplePair = Pair 10 20

値は実行時に決まりそうなので、さすがにコンパイル時にエラーにするのは無理でしょうか？（でも値をリテラルとして決め打ちで持っておけばいける？例えば上記のように 10 や 20のようにリテラルとして書けば、コンパイル時に10や20は知ってることができます）
